# Mahout - Class LongPair

Tags: mahout

I'm creating a recommendation engine with Mahout and in order to filter item-based recommendations the following method expects a "LongPair" type:

```
GenericItemBasedRecommender.mostSimilarItems(long[] itemIDs, int howMany, Rescorer<LongPair> rescorer)
```

I must admit I haven't heard about org.apache.mahout.common.LongPair, so I checked the javadoc. Unfortunately I couldn't find any example, so still don't understand what the pair of long numbers represents for the Rescorer.

Is the first one an index and the second one the value? Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

The rescorer mechanism lets you inject whatever business logic you want into the results. You can change the answer or remove an answer from the results. Here, the results are ordered by similarity between one item, and other items. Your logic may be a function of one or both of those values. So the rescorer is passing you the IDs of both items in question.